# Explainable errors in the chrome developer console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

I assume others have seen this error and it isn't something wrong with my files as I've seen this on multiple projects.

```
Uncaught TypeError: img.getAttribute is not a function
at valid_image (naptha-wick.js:1213)
at get_mouse (naptha-wick.js:2496)
at HTMLDocument.track_mouse (naptha-wick.js:2336)
```

I get this at different times when I moving my mouse. I have even tried going into the file and editing the code but with no luck. I have two questions right off the bat...

- First of all... what is naptha-wick.js? From my research, I can gather that its a chrome script loaded in by the browser but why this silly error?
- Second, why do I receive this error when my mouse is moved to different parts of the screen? I have seen this occur lots of times when clicking on a button or simply scrolling up and down the page.

If anyone knows some information that could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to an extension that lets you select text from images, project Naptha.

Comment: Any idea how I should go about dealing with it? I seem to get it quite frequently and that can't be good...

Comment: You could try to disable it from chrome. That is, if you do not use it.